# Angular / Firebase / Firestore - How to import firebase to use `serverTimestamp`

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Angular - v13.1
Firebase - ^9.6.2

In the old version of firebase, it was possible to import firebase into an Angular component to utilise the `serverTimestamp` property:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
---
this.afs.doc(`${db_path}`).set({
 dateCreated: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
)};
```

However, since being on the new version, this approach no longer seems to work. Looking through the documentation, I haven't (...yet) found anything that suggests an alternate way to import firebase into a component to use this value.

Is there a better approach to utilise the timestamp type to set as a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so the following seems to work. Not sure if it's 100% correct.

**Model/Interface**

```
import { FieldValue, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

export interface Folder extends Base {
  created: typeof serverTimestamp | FieldValue | Date;
}
```

**Component**

```
import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

---

new(){
  this.afs.collection<Model>(`path`).add({
      created: serverTimestamp()
  })
}
```

Comment: Looks right, assuming this is just a client. Though your old code seems to be following the [initialization pattern for Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize), so perhaps that's what you're looking for? Edit: If you are using angularfire, the [quickstart](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) shows that if you're using a webmodule (think `<script>`) it's imported using `"firebase/app"` but if it's on node it's [`"firebase-admin/app"`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk)